# How do I find the Docker REST API URL?

Tags: jenkins, docker

I have installed the Docker build step plugin for Jenkins.

The documentation is telling me:

```
Name      : Choose a name for this Docker cloud provider
Docker URL: The URL to use to access your Docker server API (e.g: http://172.16.42.43:4243)
```

How can I find my URL to the REST API (I have Docker installed on my host)?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you are on Linux and need to connect to Docker API on the local machine, its URL is probably `unix:///var/run/docker.sock`, like it is mentioned in documentation: *[Develop with Docker Engine SDKs and API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api/)*

> By default the Docker daemon listens on `unix:///var/run/docker.sock` and the client must have root access to interact with the daemon. If a group named docker exists on your system, docker applies ownership of the socket to the group.

This might be helpful if you are connecting to Docker from [a JetBrains IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#IDEs).

Comment: This was incredibly helpful. Trying to setup PHPStorm in ArchLinux and there is no /etc/default/docker or $DOCKER_OPTS

Comment: How do i give pycharm root access? I get permission denied on that socket. I tried adding my user to group docker as its the user that runs pycharm I'm assuming

Comment: @DrManhattan Did you try to log out of system and log in back after adding user to docker group?

Comment: I restarted the PC and it seems to have worked, Thanks @binarydata

Comment: How do you find the URL on Windows?

Comment: @SeanAnderson I can see the URL on Windows in PHPStorm > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Docker. It's tcp://localhost:2375.

Answer (score 42):

Here are two approaches.

**How do I access the Docker REST API remotely?**

> Warning: After this setup your Docker REST API port (in this case `1111`) is exposed to remote
>   access.

Here is how I enabled it on Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus).

1. Edit the docker service file (it is better to avoid directly editing `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` as it will be replaced on upgrades)

```
sudo systemctl edit docker.service
```

2. Add the following content

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:1111
```

For docker 18+, the content is a bit different:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock -H tcp://0.0.0.0:1111
```

3. Save the modified file. Here I used port `1111`, but any free port can be used.
4. Make sure the Docker service notices the modified configuration:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

5. Restart the Docker service:

```
sudo service docker restart
```

6. Test

```
curl http://localhost:1111/version
```

7. See the result

```
{"Version":"17.05.0-ce","ApiVersion":"1.29","MinAPIVersion":"1.12","GitCommit":"89658be","GoVersion":"go1.7.5","Os":"linux","Arch":"amd64","KernelVersion":"4.15.0-20-generic","BuildTime":"2017-05-04T22:10:54.638119411+00:00"}
```

Now you can use the REST API.

**How do I access the Docker REST API through a socket (from localhost)?**

Connect the internal Unix socket somewhat like this,

Using curl

```
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http:/localhost/version
```

And here is how to do it using PHP

```
$fs = fsockopen('/var/run/docker.sock');

fwrite($fs, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST: http:/images/json\r\n\r\n");

while (!feof($fs)) {
    print fread($fs,256);
}
```

In PHP 7 you can use [curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) with the **CURLOPT_UNIX_SOCKET_PATH** option.

Comment: This also works perfect in combination with running a development linux VM and the PyCharm on the Win host

Answer (score 12):

It depends on your host, but look for `/etc/default/docker` or `/var/lib/boot2docker/profile` (for [Docker Machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/overview/) hosts using a boot2docker VM).

You will see the port used by the docker daemon, for instance:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-H unix:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"
                                        ^^^^^
```

Then get the IP address of the machine hosting your Docker daemon.
(With a Docker Machine created host, that would be: `docker-machine ip <yourmachine>`.)

The URL to use is the combination of those the IP address and the port.

Comment: Urls like "http://0.0.0.0:2375" work for the chrome extension 'docker UI'

Comment: @navigaid Interesting. This one? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-docker-ui/jfaelnolkgonnjdlkfokjadedkacbnib?hl=en, seen here? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x6RVTHp5M7w

Comment: Yup. I'm playing with docker on Chromium OS.

Answer (score 4):

If you are on windows:

```
npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine
```

source: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/faqs/#how-do-i-connect-to-the-remote-docker-engine-api