# How to get the docker host URI on my localhost

Tags: docker, uri, docker-java

Is there a command that I can evaluate (`eval $COMMAND`) or an environment variable that I can inspect to get the URI of the locally running docker host? I need to be this an expression to evaluate at runtime, since I need to use it in a script intended to run on hosts where docker engine may not be running on the standard ports.

Thanks.

Comment: The command on `local docker host` or `the pc which run docker daemon & configured to use local docker host`?

Comment: When from a terminal connected to the localhost I execute `docker ps`, that command goes to some docker engine. I want to resolve the URI of the daemon that answers to that command.

Comment: You should be able to get this from `${DOCKER_HOST}`

Comment: I thought so; but that variable seems *user preference* more than *docker state handled*. I am running docker commands here and `echo ${DOCKER_HOST}` returns empty.

Comment: In my particular case, it is not a remote host, it is the local host. Somehow when I issue `docker ...`, the docker client knows how to reach a docker engine or fail trying, I just need a command that can evaluate to such URI, maybe even some docker utility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure I have fully understood your question but hopefully this may shed some light.

The docker command is just a REST client. By default the client connects to the unix-socket `/var/run/docker.sock` to send requests to the docker daemon. 
You can practically achieve the same thing by running `curl`:

```
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http:/localhost/version
```

Now if your docker daemon was configured for remote access, you probably have the URI information in the `docker.service` service file. See this post
[How do I find the Docker REST API URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178824/how-do-i-find-the-docker-rest-api-url).

Hope that helps

Comment: Nice! that's exactly what I was looking for. I didn't have very clear how the client *addressed* the daemon though; but this totally clear things up in the direction I needed, thanks!

Comment: I am glad it helped

Answer (score -1):

Hey you can use ps command on the host and grep docker like below

```
>ps aux | grep docker
root      1729  0.0  0.3 2222936 56288 ?  Ssl  May08   8:05  /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

then you can get which port(s) or sock it is linked with

Comment: That doesn't give me the URI, nor portions of it reliably; and it most hosts there are plenty of entries in `ps` matching `docker`

Comment: then grep whole path /usr/bin/dockerd

Comment: It doesn't work. If you don't know, that's alright, no need to keep guessing or hacking away until finding something that may stick.