# When using Docker Desktop for Windows, how do you find the URL of the Docker daemon?

Tags: docker

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178824/how-do-i-find-the-docker-rest-api-url), but I am asking this about Windows, whereas the answers there pertain more to Linux/Unix.

I am developing ASP.NET Core Microservices on Windows 10, using Docker Desktop.  I want to write .NET Core tests that can interact directly with the Docker daemon.  This basically involves one of two things:

1. interacting with Windows's shell inside the tests, or
2. using APIs to interact with Docker directly, which involves getting the URL.

The problem is that I don't see anywhere that the URL is listed or can be found.  Where can this be located?

---

In this particular situation, I probably wouldn't mind using [Docker.DotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/Docker.DotNet), which itself seems to wrap around some sort of REST API for Docker.  However Docker.DotNet's documentation has an error on the front page, saying that `DockerClientConfiguration` can be instantiated without passing in any arguments, in order to interact with the local Docker daemon.  When trying that though, a compilation error is produced, and Intellisense shows that the `endpoint` parameter is always required.  If I try to call some sort of REST API directly, I'm *still* going to need a URL to point to.

Even `docker info` doesn't seem to give a clear answer, though it does provide a URL for `Insecure Registries`.  Docker Desktop doesn't describe anything.  Information online is either non-applicable for Windows or otherwise irrelevant.

---

**EDIT:**

In response to a quick answer, there *is* the following setting on Docker Desktop, which is *unchecked* by default:

```
Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS
```

If this is always the URL, regardless of whether that box is checked or not, then that is the answer.  If so, please specify.  I did see this before, but because it was sitting next to a checkbox, I didn't feel it could be relied upon, particularly while using with a new API that I'm trying to learn at the same time.

When using Postman to try to call the [List Containers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/#tag/Container) endpoint from Docker's REST API directly, that URL doesn't appear to be working, either through TCP or HTTP.  Same situation with the addresses listed under Resources>Network.

Answer (score 1):

run docker context list command to see list of endpoints

> docker context ls

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The URL to the daemon is clearly outlined in the settings. https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/images/settings-general.png

Comment: in macOS Catalina, I am unable to find the endpoint URL in docker-desktop settings page