# How to expose Docker TCP socket on WSL2? (WSL-installed Docker, not Docker Desktop)

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, docker-daemon

I want to connect to Docker TCP socket running in WSL2 via PyCharm. I can't seem to expose the socket, I think possibly because there's limited control of docker-daemon within WSL2 (systemctl)? I can't use Docker Desktop because I need GPU support (Windows Dev Channel + nvidia-docker). I've tried the following:

#### export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://0.0.0.0:2375

```
$ export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://0.0.0.0:2375
$ sudo service docker restart
$ docker context ls
NAME                DESCRIPTION                               DOCKER ENDPOINT      KUBERNETES ENDPOINT   ORCHESTRATOR
default *           Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration   tcp://0.0.0.0:2375                         swarm
Warning: DOCKER_HOST environment variable overrides the active context. To use a context, either set the global --context flag, or unset DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
$ curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http:/localhost/version
{"Platform":{"Name":"Docker Engine - Community"},"Components":[{"Name":"Engine","Version":"19.03.11","Details":{"ApiVersion":"1.40","Arch":"amd64","BuildTime":"2020-06-01T09:10:54.000000000+00:00","Experimental":"false","GitCommit":"42e35e61f3","GoVersion":"go1.13.10","KernelVersion":"4.19.121-microsoft-standard","MinAPIVersion":"1.12","Os":"linux"}},{"Name":"containerd","Version":"1.2.13","Details":{"GitCommit":"7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429"}},{"Name":"runc","Version":"1.0.0-rc10","Details":{"GitCommit":"dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd"}},{"Name":"docker-init","Version":"0.18.0","Details":{"GitCommit":"fec3683"}}],"Version":"19.03.11","ApiVersion":"1.40","MinAPIVersion":"1.12","GitCommit":"42e35e61f3","GoVersion":"go1.13.10","Os":"linux","Arch":"amd64","KernelVersion":"4.19.121-microsoft-standard","BuildTime":"2020-06-01T09:10:54.000000000+00:00"}
$ curl http://localhost:2375/version
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 2375: Connection refused
```

The final command I expect to give a result like `{"Version":"17.05.0-ce","ApiVersion":"...}` but connection refused. Indeed, if I try to connect via Windows host Pycharm it refuses connection. I also see many tutorials / SO posts saying not to use this DOCKER_HOST approach, but I'm not sure why.

#### /lib/systemd/system/docker.service > ExecStart

Per [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51017236/362790), [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/843332), [ivankrizsan](https://www.ivankrizsan.se/2016/05/18/enabling-docker-remote-api-on-ubuntu-16-04/), I edited `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` with `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375`. But when I try `systemctl daemon-reload` it errors; WSL2 doesn't support `systemctl` commands ([WSL/457](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/issues/457)).

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
```

I also tried restarting WSL2 (Powershell `wsl --shutdown`, re-open WSL2) in case docker-daemon will pick those change up, but no cigar.

```
$ curl http://localhost:2375/version
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 2375: Connection refused
```

#### /etc/default/docker > DOCKER_OPTS

Per [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37179733/362790), I edited `/etc/default/docker` with `DOCKER_OPTS="-H unix:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"` then `sudo service docker restart`. Same connection refused errors.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Quick-Fix (insecure)

From [Gist](https://gist.github.com/styblope/dc55e0ad2a9848f2cc3307d4819d819f)

#### 1. `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

```
{"hosts": ["tcp://0.0.0.0:2375", "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"]}
```

#### 2. `sudo service docker restart`

---

### Long-Fix (TLS)

TLS support: [more detailed serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/926857/144946), [step-by-step blog post](https://medium.com/trabe/using-docker-engine-api-securely-584e0882158e). If you're setting up Docker on server, I recommend following the blog post. For me I just wanted Docker in WSL2, socket reachable by Windows (PyCharm), and TLS secure. So my modifications use `~/.docker` & `localhost` (rather than root folders & FQDN). Here are my steps:

#### 1. `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

```
"hosts": ["unix:///var/run/docker.sock", "tcp://0.0.0.0:2376"],
"tlscacert": "/home/lefnire/.docker/certs/ca.pem",
"tlscert": "/home/lefnire/.docker/certs/server-cert.pem",
"tlskey": "/home/lefnire/.docker/certs/server-key.pem",
"tlsverify": true
```

Note I'm using `~/.docker/certs` instead of `/etc/docker/certs`. I hit permission snags with PyCharm needing access to "Certificates Folder", even with `chmod -v 0444 x` attempts.

#### 2. Certs

```
$ mkdir ~/.docker/certs
$ cd ~/.docker/certs
$ openssl genrsa -aes256 -out ca-key.pem 4096  # enter passphrase
$ openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca-key.pem -sha256 -out ca.pem  # enter localhost at FQDN step
$ openssl genrsa -out server-key.pem 4096
$ openssl req -subj "/CN=localhost" -sha256 -new -key server-key.pem -out server.csr
$ openssl x509 -req -days 365 -sha256 -in server.csr -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -CAcreateserial -out server-cert.pem
$ echo subjectAltName = DNS:localhost,IP:127.0.0.1 >> extfile.cnf
$ echo extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth >> extfile.cnf
$ openssl x509 -req -days 365 -sha256 -in server.csr -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -CAcreateserial -out server-cert.pem -extfile extfile.cnf
$ openssl genrsa -out key.pem 4096
$ openssl req -subj '/CN=client' -new -key key.pem -out client.csr
$ echo extendedKeyUsage = clientAuth > extfile-client.cnf
$ openssl x509 -req -days 365 -sha256 -in client.csr -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -CAcreateserial -out cert.pem -extfile extfile-client.cnf
```

Ignore openssl RAND errors (or [fix it](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/7754#issuecomment-653847708))

#### 3. `sudo service docker restart`

#### 4. PyCharm (optional)

1. File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Docker

   1. Add Docker (or click existing) > [x] TCP Socket
   2. Engine API URL: `https://localhost:2376`
   3. Certificates Folder: `\\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04\home\lefnire\.docker\certs`
2. File > Settings > Project: [my-proj] > Python Interpreter

   1. Dropdown > Show All... > Add > Docker

Comment: In my case, I am running a wsl2 ubuntu environment, docker compose was looking for unix:///mnt/wsl/shared-docker/docker.sock to connect and docker looking for unix:///var/run/docker.sock, so as a workaround, I served both of them : {"hosts": ["tcp://0.0.0.0:2375", "unix:///var/run/docker.sock", unix:///mnt/wsl/shared-docker/docker.sock]}, a better solution should be to figure out, what config they are looking for to connect, NB. the export DOCKER_HOST is ignored by both of them

Answer (score 0):

in my case, the problem is

> -H fd://

fixed by [Failed to load listeners](https://forums.docker.com/t/failed-to-load-listeners-no-sockets-found-via-socket-activation-make-sure-the-service-was-started-by-systemd/62505)

1. check log. `tail -f /var/log/docker.log`

failed to load listeners: no sockets found via socket activation: make sure the service was started by systemd

2. edit file `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` , replace **fd://** to **unix://**